# How can I prove the following problem is NP complete?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, proof-techniques, np

### The problem:

I have a list $\displaystyle S=\{s_{1} ,s_{2} ,\dotsc ,s_{n}\}$ places. Each unordered pair of places has cost and gain: $\displaystyle c\{s_{i} ,s_{j}\} \in \mathbb{N}$, $\displaystyle g\{s_{i} ,s_{j}\} \in \mathbb{N}$. Also the pairs are only for $\displaystyle i\neq j$.

I have two numbers: $ $$\displaystyle b\in \mathbb{N}$, $\displaystyle p\in \mathbb{N}$.

The problem is to check wether it exist a combination of pairs such that:

$\displaystyle c_{1} +c_{2} +\dotsc +c_{m} \leqslant b$ and $\displaystyle g_{1} +g_{2} +\dotsc +g_{m} \geqslant p$. Where of course $\displaystyle c_{i} ,g_{i}$ are cost and gain of a used pair $s_i$.

To show it is NP-complete I have to show a Karp reduction.

---

There are some problems we've studies and so that I can use:

Clique, Composite, SAT - Satisfiability problem, 3SAT, CSAT, IS - Independent Set, VC - Vertex, Cover, DHC - Directed Hamilton Cycle, HC - Hamilton Cycle, DS - Dominating Set, SSS - Subset, Set, 3COL, Partition, Bin-Packing.

Since it's talking about a sum I thought of using Subset-sum. If I set $\displaystyle p=b=k$, and I set $\displaystyle c_{i} =g_{i}$ for each $\displaystyle i$, then it really is just a sum question, to find a combination of elements of sum $\displaystyle k$.

But what it's complicating it for me is that if I have $\displaystyle n$ elements, I will have $\displaystyle \frac{n^{2} -n}{2}$ pairs, and so these many different costs. How can I rewrite the $\displaystyle n$ elements of partition, into some $\displaystyle k$ elements here such that there are $\displaystyle \frac{k^{2} -k}{2} =n$ pairs?

I've thought maybe I can only assign the cost to the first $\displaystyle n$ elements, and then all the rest to $\displaystyle 0$, but then cost and gain must be natural numbers.

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe a reduction from subset-sum would be easier

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Can the pairs you choose name a place multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an easy reduction from Knapsack.

> Knapsack:
>
> - Input: a list of couples (value, weight) $\{(v_1, w_1), …, (v_n,w_n)\}$, a maximum weight $W$, a target value $V$
> - Question: is there a subset $S \subset [\![1, n]\!]$ such that $\sum\limits_{i\in S} v_i \geq V$ and $\sum\limits_{i\in S} w_i \leq W$

Now given an input of knapsack, let's construct an input of your problem: add a $n+1$-th element, and consider:

- $\forall (i, j) \in [\![1, n]\!]$ with $i\neq j$, we set $c\{i, j\} = \infty$  and $c\{i, n+1\} = w_i$
- $\forall (i, j) \in [\![1, n]\!]$ with $i\neq j$, we set $g\{i, j\} = 0$  and $g\{i, n+1\} = v_i$
- set $b = W$ and $p = V$

Then this instance has a solution of your problem if and only if the input of knapsack has a solution. Since knapsack is $NP$-complete, this proves the $NP$-hardness of your problem.

Comment: Hi, we haven't studied Knapsack so I can't use it. But I have seen NP reductions from SSS or Partition to Knapsack. The problem is in this case I can't assign a cost of $0$ or infinity, since it should be a natural number.

Comment: You can just set $c\{i, j\} = W + 1$, since we only want to prevent selecting wrong pairs. As for $g\{i,j\}$ with $i,j\leq n$, their values don't matter since we won't be selecting these pairs (because of the cost).

Comment: Ah right, didn't think about that but true, thank you!